# How to sum field base on status field with eloquent laravel (with)

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-6, laravel-query-builder

I have case sum of data
**actual result**: return 0
**Expected result** not return 0.

I have table like

Transaction

| id | user_id | amount_load | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1f | 3edf | 100000 | 1 |

Log Transaction

| id | trx_id | amount_pay | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32f | 1f | 10000 | 1 |
| 23d | 1f | 50000 | 1 |
| 12e | 1f | 1000 | 3 |

info about status:

| ID | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | not paid |
| 1 | paid not full |
| 2 | paided |
| 3 | refunded |

My code on controller

```
$data = Transaction::select('user_id')->groupBy(‘user_id’)
->with([LogTransaction => function ($query) {
     $query->sumRefund();
}]);
```

Model Transaction.php

```
public function scopeSelectDefault($q) {
   return $q->selectRaw(‘id, user_id, amount_load, status’);    
}

//RELATION
public function logTransaction()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LogTransaction', 'trx_id', 'id');
}
```

Model LogTransaction.php

```
 public function scopeSumRefund($q) {
   return $q->selectRaw(‘coalesce(SUM(amount_pay) FILTER (WHERE status  = '3'),0) AS total_refund’);    
}

// RELATION
public function transaction($query, $order)
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Transaction', 'id');
}
```

**expected result**: `total_refund` on relation resulting 1000 base status = 3

other information:
laravel ^6.0
postgres 12.0

please help

Comment: Model Transaction.php doesn't have to use `selectRaw()` 

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can use the Laravel custom attribute option and you can define it in your Transactions Model like so

```
public function getTotalRefundAttribute() {
   return $this->logTransaction ? $this->logTransaction->where('status', 3)->sum('amount_pay') : null;
}
```

And now when you get any Transaction instance it will have an extra attribute called `total_refund` where you can see the total amount. But make sure you actually have eloquent relations setup between Transaction and LogTransactions models

Comment: I have made update information setup relations and other informations. And I added getTotalRefundAttribute() but I can't find attribute **total_refund**

Comment: oke I founded the **total_refund** but it's still return 0 @dz0nika

Comment: try and do this inside your controller dd($transaction->logTransaction->where('status', 3)->get()); If this returns the valid data then you have not setup the attribute correctly.

Comment: I told you to do that so you can see if you relation actually works.

Comment: it's return error : "Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::logTransaction()"